# How to write a formula in calc so that the formula contains ref to a cell which in turn contains ref to a different cell?

Tags: openoffice-calc

Say I want to write a formula in 5 cells of column D (D1 to D5) based on a column which may vary. In other words, the second column can be B (B1 to B5) or C (C1 to C5) or any other columns. I don't know. But i need the results in column D (D1 to D5). Therefore I make cells E1 to E5 the input cells. Here I shall mention the second column from time to time. Now, I want a formula on D1 to D5 in such a way that it picks up the column in question from E1 to E5.

Say I want to write a logical function on D1; =IF("XYZ"E1>0;1;0). "XYZ" is the function I want from you. If I have written B1 in E1,  E1 becomes B1 and it calculates the value of cell B1.

I don't want any macro based solutions, please!

Answer (score 0):

You're searching the **[INDIRECT()](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_INDIRECT_function)** function. You can use it together with [**CONCATENATE()**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_CONCATENATE_function) to create dynamic cell references.